# Data model for dynamodb single table solution for a job portal

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

we are implementing a job portal based on a serverless architecture in aws. All the data should be saved in one single dynamodb table. Some of the Entities are User (Candidate or Employer), Job and Application. The biggest challenge we are facing right now is, saving the jobs in a way that the a job search (from candidates) is as accurate as possible. The access pattern should look like this: Find all Jobs containing this hard skills With this EmploymentType With this experienceLevel for this Location

On the other hand, the access pattern from the employers perspective, is much easier: Find All Jobs of my Company.

We appreciate every hint or idea how to model this in a dynamodb?

Thanks in advance.

Regards from Germany

PS: The more we think about it, the more we have the feelding, that especially the search for jobs from the candidate perspective needs a solution like Amazon CloudSearch or elasticsearch. But before we make this decision, we wanted to have some more opinions.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in pointing out that the main challenge you are facing is not data access (return all job postings for `partitionKey = myCompany`), but a document search across a set of synonyms in the space of hard skills / employment type / location, so an optimal solution should combine a database capability and a [search capability](https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/document-search/).

Comment: Thnx for your answer Alex.